# Elasticsearch - pass fuzziness parameter in query_string

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a fuzzy query with customized `AUTO:10,20` [fuzziness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness) value.

```
{
"query": {
 "match": {
   "name": {
     "query": "nike",
     "fuzziness": "AUTO:10,20"
   }
 }
}
}
```

How to convert it to a [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) query? I tried `nike~AUTO:10,20` but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene syntax only allows you to specify "fuzziness" with the tilde symbol "~", optionally followed by 0, 1 or 2 to indicate the edit distance.

Elasticsearch Query DSL supports a configurable special value for AUTO which then is used to build the proper Lucene query.

You would need to implement that logic on your application side, by evaluating the desired edit distance based on the length of your search term and then use `<searchTerm>~<editDistance>` in your `query_string`-query.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with `query_strng` as well, let me show using the same example as OP provided, both `match_query` provided by OP matches and `query_string` fetches the same document with same `score`.

And according to [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) and [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness) ES docs, Elasticsearch supports `AUTO:10,20` format, which is shown in my example as well.

Also

### Index mapping

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index some doc

```
{
   "name" : "nike"
}
```

### Search query using match with fuzziness

```
{
"query": {
 "match": {
   "name": {
     "query": "nike",
     "fuzziness": "AUTO:10,20"
   }
 }
}
}
```

And result

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "so-query",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.9808292,
            "_source": {
               "name": "nike"
            }
         }
      ]
```

### Query_string with fuzziness

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "fields": ["name"],
            "query": "nike",
            "fuzziness": "AUTO:10,20"
        }
    }
}
```

And result

```
 "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "so-query",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.9808292,
            "_source": {
               "name": "nike"
            }
         }
      ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually want the solution of achieving this in single sentence like `nike~1`. @Daniel Schneiter replied it is not possible.

Comment: This is because I'm using AWS Neptune Full-Text Search (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/full-text-search-gremlin.html) solution. This solution only supports queries in Lucene syntax.